# streambuilder in elevation attribute of appbar in flutter

Tags: flutter

i am trying to change the elevation of my appbar depending on the screen the user will click on.  i was using setState before but prefer to do it with streambuilder because of the many component in my screen.
the problem i am having is that i am getting a error when using streambuilder

here is my code

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: StreamBuilder<Object>(
            stream: bloc.titleStream,
            initialData: home,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return Text(snapshot.data);
            }
        ),
        backgroundColor: colorPrimary,
        elevation: StreamBuilder<double>(
            stream: bloc.appBarElevetionStream,
           // initialData: 0.0,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return snapshot.data.toDouble();
            }
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Builder(
              builder: (context) => bloc.navigationProvider.currentNavigation == home ?
                   homeCalendar(context):otherCalendar(context) //if it's not 0 we return an empty widget
          )
        ],
      ),
      drawer: DrawerNavigation(),
      body: homeScreen()
);
```

here is the code for the bloc

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:finsec/features/common/presentation/bloc/navigation_provider.dart';

class NavigationDrawerBloc {
  final navigationController = StreamController();
  StreamController<String> _title = StreamController<String>();
  StreamController<String> _drawerItemColor = StreamController<String>();
  StreamController<double> _appBarElevetion = StreamController<double>();

  NavigationProvider navigationProvider = new NavigationProvider();

  Stream get getNavigation => navigationController.stream;
  Stream<String> get titleStream => _title.stream;
  Stream<String> get itemColorStream => _drawerItemColor.stream;
  Stream<double> get appBarElevetionStream => _appBarElevetion.stream;


  // Color color = Color(0xffECECEC);

  void updateNavigation(String navigation, String title, double elevation) {
    navigationProvider.updateNavigation(navigation, title, elevation);
    navigationController.sink.add(navigationProvider.currentNavigation);
    _title.sink.add(title);
    _drawerItemColor.sink.add('gray');
    _appBarElevetion.sink.add(elevation);

  }

  void dispose() {
    navigationController.close();
    _title.close();
  }
}

final bloc = NavigationDrawerBloc();
```

my provider class

```
import 'package:finsec/core/res/export_resources.dart';

class NavigationProvider {
  String currentNavigation = home;
  String currentTitle = home;
  String drawerItemColor = 'gray';
  double appBarElevation = 0.0;

  void updateNavigation(String navigation, String title, double elevation) {
    currentNavigation = navigation;
    currentTitle = title;
    drawerItemColor = 'gray';
    appBarElevation = elevation;
  }
}
```

i am getting error in the elevation attribute of appbar in the build function

```
  elevation: StreamBuilder<double>(
            stream: bloc.appBarElevetionStream,
           // initialData: 0.0,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return snapshot.data.toDouble();
            }
        ),
```

the error is:  the argument type StreamBuilder can't be assigned to the parameter type of double.
the return type 'double' isnt a 'widget' as require  by the closure's context

is there any way i can cast the streambuilder output to a double so that i can use it in the elevation attribute of appbar?  how can i use streambuilder in elevation attribute?  thanks in advance

Comment: Wrap your `Scaffold` with the `StreamBuilder`.

Comment: thank you Christopher.  can you show me and provide code on how to wrap the scaffold with streambuilder and access the elevation and title from my example above? im new to streambuilder and i am not sure how to wrap and access the element so that i can populate the title and elevation element which both are using streambuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StreamBuilder` doesn't simply return a value, it is a widget itself with a builder that provides the value of the stream when it's available. Wrap your `StreamBuilder` around the `Scaffold` and access the value the same way.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder<double>(
    stream: bloc.appBarElevetionStream,
    initialData: 0.0,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: StreamBuilder<Object>(
              stream: bloc.titleStream,
              initialData: home,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Text(snapshot.data);
              }
          ),
          backgroundColor: colorPrimary,
          elevation: snapshot.data,
          actions: <Widget>[
            Builder(
              builder: (context) => bloc.navigationProvider.currentNavigation == home ?
                homeCalendar(context):otherCalendar(context) //if it's not 0 we return an empty widget
            )
          ],
        ),
        drawer: DrawerNavigation(),
        body: homeScreen()
      );
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`StreamBuilder` returns a `widget`. The `double` in your `StreamBuilder` is the type of data returned by `stream` and not `StreamBuilder`.

As specified in the comments wrap the `Scaffold` in the `Stream Bulder` or use your previous method of using `setState`.

Comment: Hi Navaneeth, thanks for your input.   can you show me and provide code on how to wrap the scaffold with streambuilder and access the elevation and title from my example above? im new to streambuilder and i am not sure how to wrap and access the element so that i can populate the title and elevation element which both are using streambuilder.